# Voting corrected for a single vote

Tags: support, voting

Today I got -10 with label "voting corrected". [Its page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) says:

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them.

But -10 can be reverting of a single upvote only, can't it? Why does the system revert a single vote?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: it's for sure a small side effect of a big "voting corrected" where other users are involved

Comment: I checked the vote in question and I can confirm it was a single duplicate upvote.

Comment: @Dharman I don't think the duplicate is relevant to this situation

Comment: @TemaniAfif Why not? It explains that it's a bug that is being currently reversed

Comment: @Dharman maybe I am not understanding the question then.

Comment: @TemaniAfif The question is asking why only a single upvote was reversed. The answer is because the staff is currently invalidating all duplicate votes that happened over the years. Qwertiy received a single duplicate upvote that got reversed just now.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, duplicate seems nice if the script actually was run. But it would be nice to update description page.

Comment: @Qwertiy "*if the script actually was run.*" on 24th of June (Friday) Yaakov said "*We'll be invalidating all the dupes over the next week,*". Today is 27th of June (Monday) and is next week. It's quite reasonable to assume that the cleanup has started. A lot of times SE announce when they would *start* some longer running task and then announce when it's finished.

Comment: The canonical post on Über Meta is *[Upcoming cleanup of duplicated votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379788/)*.